# What is the replacement for deprecated MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA in Android Q?

Tags: android

Currently, we are using `MediaStore` and `CursorLoader` to build a file picker.

We are using `MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")`

We notice `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated in Android Q, although it seems still function-able at this moment.

```
String albumCoverPath = albums.getString(albums.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
// allAlbumCoverPath -> /storage/emulated/0/Download/0.jpg
```

But, I afraid this might break in the future, due to deprecation. May I know what is the replacement for `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`?

Comment: Could you find a solution of this? I am stuck at same point